# How to configure dependencies from a java custom gradle plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to write a custom gradle plugin written in java.
I have the core functionality already written in a groovy build script.
The first part is to declare some core dependencies that will always be used.
The second part is to add a helper closure to the dependencies section.
This closure will take a name as an argument and based upon that decide what dependencies to include.
If the helper closure is never used, the core dependencies will still be included.

The groovy script implementation is as follows.
The core dependencies are declared in the standard dependencies section.

```
dependencies {
    
    implementation '<dependency name>'
    
}
```

The helper closure is implemented like this.

```
dependencies.ext.helper = { name ->
    
    // Some logic that decides which dependencies to include based on name arg ...
    
    // For each dependency to include ...
    dependencies.implementation "<dependency name>"
    
}
```

The helper closure can then be used in the dependencies section of a `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    
    helper 'some name'
    
}
```

I now want to convert this to a standalone plugin written in java.

A plugin written in java has the following main class.

```
package some.package;

import org.gradle.api.*;

public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> 
    
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project){
        
    }
    
}
```

How do I best access the dependencies section from the apply method?
How can I use the access to implement the functionality I want?

I found the `getDependecies()` and `dependencies(Closure)` methods on the project object that might be useful.
I don't know the difference between them, but I suspect it has to do with deferred configuration.
The `dependencies` one also requires a closure which I'm unsure how to use.
This seems to indicate that the `dependencies(Closure)` is the deferred one and that it is preferable.
Both seem to lead to a DependencyHandler object which can probably be used to implement the functionality I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDependencies()` and `dependencies(Closure)` are doing the same thing. `Closure` is a Groovy concept for writing nice DSLs, so calling that in a Groovy script is an idiomatic way if you are using Groovy. Doing so you lose type-safety though so it doesn't seem a great idea trying to use it in Java.

Neither is about deferred configuration. The [`DependencyHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html) you are accessing is a 'bucket' that is always there and initialised on the Project object, so there is no issue with accessing it at any time.

So call `getDependencies()` and get stuck in! You can write something like:

```java
@Override
public void apply(Project project) {
    DependencyHandler dependencies = project.getDependencies();
    dependencies.add(
        JavaPlugin.IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIGURATION_NAME, dependencyOne
    );
    if (name != null)
        addHelperDependencies(name, dependencies);
}
    
private void addHelperDependencies(String name, DependencyHandler dependencies) {
    dependencies.add(
        JavaPlugin.IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIGURATION_NAME, getDependencyTwo(name)
    );
}
    
private String getDependencyTwo(String name) {
    return "aMostUsefulDependency" + name;
}
```

You will have to consider how to get hold of the `name` variable. I imagine you will want to do this by [adding a project extension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build). Using the [Gradle lazy API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#lazy_configuration) (ie using `Property` and `Provider` objects) is highly recommended to keep your build running smoothly as your project grows.